# AsyncTask doInBackground does not run

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm having a problem with the AsyncTask class. It seems like my task stops working after  creating 4 or 5 tasks.

Im having 2 activities. MainActivity which only holds a button that starts a second activity called ImageActivity.

ImageActivity is very simple. it got an onCreate that sets the layout, and then it starts a new AsyncTask that loads an image from the internet. This works fine the first few times. But than it suddenly stops working. The onPreExecute method is run every time, but not the doInBackground method. I have tried to simplify the doInBackground with a sleeping loop, and the same thing happens. I cant understand this behavour since the asynctask is both canceled and set to null in the onDestroy method. So every time i start a new ImageActivity, i also create a fresh AsyncTask.

I recreate the ImageActivity and the task by hitting the back button, and than clicking the button on the MainActivity.

Any ideas anyone? I'm really struggling with this one.

UPDATE: Code that starts the ImageActivity (inside a button onClickListener)

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
intent.setClassName(this, ImageActivity.class.getName());
startActivity(intent);
```

The code above starts this activity

```
    public class ImageActivity extends Activity {

    private AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> task;

    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute()
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "onPreExecute()");
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground() -- Here is the download");
                // downloadBitmap("http://mydomain.com/image.jpg")
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void res)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute()");
                if(isCancelled()){
                    return;
                }
            }
        }.execute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        task.cancel(true);
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

I have tested using a combination of traditional Threads and runOnUiThread method, and it seems to work better. Now the thread runs every time.

Comment: Post your code. How are you calling it. We have no idea how to help you without code

Comment: Having exactly the same issue, after starting multiple AsyncTasks in my app, the app only executes up to onPreExecute(), but does not enter doInBackground(). Trying your Thread approach now..

Comment: I am having the same problem.  The weird thing is that it varies from device to device.  It occurs on a tablet (Android 4.0), but a phone (Android 2.3.4) running exactly the same code does not have it.

Comment: in my case `doInBackground` works but `Log.d()` inside it does not work!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Removing the AsyncTask and using a **traditional Thread** instead of combining it with **runOnUiThread** seems to work. But I still have not found the reason why the AsyncTask is so "unstable".

Here is the code that works for me:

```
public class ImageActivity extends Activity {

    private Thread worker;

    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        worker = new Thread(new Runnable(){

            private void updateUI(final List<Object> list)
            {
                if(worker.isInterrupted()){
                    return;
                }
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        // Update view and remove loading spinner etc...
                    }
                });
            }

            private List<Object> download()
            {
                // Simulate download
                SystemClock.sleep(1000);
                return new ArrayList<Object>();
            }

            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "Thread run()");
                updateUI(download());
            }

        });
        worker.start(); }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        worker.interrupt();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have the same problem (posted it here on SO a litle while back and it didnt solve the problem) a Google search brought me here :)

Comment: This sheds light on why AsyncTask may have failed you (and me!): http://foo.jasonhudgins.com/2010/05/limitations-of-asynctask.html

Comment: Just sharing a thought, I recently ran into something voodoo like behavior of `AsyncTask`. However, I got past it after shutting down an already running `AsyncTask` in the background. Weird, but it worked for me.

Comment: My answer outlines the specific reason for the failure. http://stackoverflow.com/a/20620623/9636

Answer (score 7):

I ran into similar problem.  You can't have multiple Asynctasks running in parallel up until SDK 11.  Check [here for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068984/running-multiple-asynctasks-at-the-same-time-not-possible)

Answer (score 6):

I just ran into this problem as well. If you use `AsyncTask.execute`, your task is run on a serial queue (from the Android 4.3 source):

> When first introduced, AsyncTasks were executed serially on a single
>   background thread. Starting with DONUT, this was changed to a pool of
>   threads allowing multiple tasks to operate in parallel. Starting with
>   HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common
>   application errors caused by parallel execution.

This is consistent with behavior that I saw. I had an `AsyncTask` popped up a dialog in `doInBackground` and blocked until the dialog was closed. The dialog needed its own `AsyncTask` to complete. The dialog's `AsyncTask.doInBackground` method never executed because the original `AsyncTask` was still blocked.

The solution is to execute the second `AsyncTask` in a separate `Executor`.

Comment: doInBackground() should not me calling UI methods (e.g. to pop-up a Dialog as you mention).

Comment: I showed the dialog on the main thread, but it was triggered by `doInBackground`.

Comment: This is the correct answer that should be accepted. (Just finished my own investigation on the topic and came to the same conclusion - separate Executor)

Comment: So if I'm reading this documentation right, they went from serial execution to parallel execution back to serial execution? And now if we need to execute two or more AsyncTasks concurrently, we need to use multiple executors that each run on their own thread?

Comment: Yes, or use a single parallel executor.

Answer (score 1):

Use traceview to investigate -- or obtain a thread dump.  My guess is that one of your AsyncTask threads are hanging on downloading.

AsyncTask has a small thread pool, so if one of your tasks hangs, it could end up blocking your thread pool.

Here's a quick test you can run -- on 4.3, I see that I have only 5 concurrent threads I can run.  When one thread exits, other threads start up.

```
  private void testAsyncTasks() {

        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
              final int tid = i;
              new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void>() {
                    protected void onPreExecute() {
                          Log.d("ASYNCTASK", "Pre execute for task : " + tid);
                    };

                    @Override
                    protected Void doInBackground(Integer... args) {
                          int taskid = args[0];
                          long started = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
                          Log.d("ASYNCTASK", "Executing task: " + taskid + " at " + started);
                          for (int j = 1; j <= 20; j++) {
                                Log.d("ASYNCTASK", "   task " + taskid + ", time=" + (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - started));
                                SystemClock.sleep(1000);
                          }
                          return null;
                    }

                    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                          Log.d("ASYNCTASK", "Post execute for task : " + tid);
                    };
              }.execute(i);

        }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to worry about housekeeping thread in Android as it is managed by the system.

Please also post the image download method. Have you also tried to not cancel the thread in the onDestroy() method? How are you returning the the image to your UI thread?

Comment: The downloadBitmap method is a bit long, and its not the problem. I get the same problem if i try Thread.sleep(5000) simulating a slow download. When i use the Thread.sleep, I can start the ImageActivity 3-4 times and the task works. After that the task only prints onPreExecute and not the "doInBackground" log-message, meaning that it is never called for some reason. And yes, i have tried not to cancel the task, but i didn't help.

Comment: Is there more code you've omitted?

Answer (score 0):

The problem I believe is with the heavy image download task. Even if you cancel the async task the image download will continue to execute and the async task does not finish until the download is complete. You might want to check the isCancelled() method on AyncTask while the download is going on and kill the download if the task is cancelled.

For reference, heres the documentation on cancel() method :
*Attempts to cancel execution of this task. This attempt will fail if the task has already completed, already been cancelled, or could not be cancelled for some other reason. If successful, and this task has not started when cancel is called, this task should never run. If the task has already started, then the mayInterruptIfRunning parameter determines whether the thread executing this task should be interrupted in an attempt to stop the task.
Calling this method will result in onCancelled(Object) being invoked on the UI thread after doInBackground(Object[]) returns. Calling this method guarantees that onPostExecute(Object) is never invoked. After invoking this method, you should check the value returned by isCancelled() periodically from doInBackground(Object[]) to finish the task as early as possible.*

Answer (score 0):

I had this too, no real reason for not starting. I've noticed that after restarting adb it worked again. Not sure why this is, but it did work for me