# AsycTask Doesn't Execute

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have come across many posts regarding the issue of AsycTask not running and wanted to confirm if that is indeed the issue with my implementation. [Should I try to implement this method instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080808/asynctask-doinbackground-does-not-run/4085140#4085140)

I call the following method in my onCreate method using `new GetRoutes().execute("test");`. The information provided by the AsyncTask is used to build a ListView of parsed information. However, this method does not update the "values" array as it should.

```
private class GetRoutes extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]> {
    @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground(String... urls) {
      List<String> in = new ArrayList<String>();
          try{
            RouteReader route = new RouteReader();
            in = route.parse(new URL(RouteReader.URI).openStream());
        } catch(IOException iox){
            in.add("Major poopoo");
            //in.add(getResources().getString(R.string.loading_error));
        } catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException aiob){
            in.add("Minor poopoo");
            //in.add(getResources().getString(R.string.loading_error));
        } catch(NullPointerException npe){
            in.add("Small poopoo");
            //in.add(getResources().getString(R.string.loading_error));
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            in.add(getResources().getString(R.string.loading_error));
        }
      return in.toArray(new String[in.size()]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
      values = result;
    }
}
```

The RouteReader class is as follows:

```
public class RouteReader {
    private XmlPullParser parser;

    public final static String URI = 
            "http://webservices.nextbus.com/service/publicXMLFeed?command=routeList&a=ttc";

    public RouteReader(){
         parser = Xml.newPullParser();
    }

     public List<String> parse(InputStream in) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
            try {
                parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
                parser.setInput(in, null);
                parser.nextTag();
                return readFeed(parser);
            } finally {
                in.close();
            }
     }

     private List<String> readFeed(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
            List<String> entries = new ArrayList<String>();

            parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "body");
            while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                    continue;
                }
                String name = parser.getName();
                if (name.equals("route")) {
                    entries.add(parser.getAttributeValue(null, "id"));
                    System.out.println(parser.getAttributeValue(null, "id"));
                }
            }  
            return entries;
        }
    }
```

Could you please help me in pinpointing the issue with this implementation?

Comment: Is it possible that you try to access the value of `values` directly after calling `new GetRoutes().execute("test");`? I.e. not waiting for the async result set by `onPostExecute` (the code that uses the result must be triggered from `onPostExecute`)

Comment: @zapl Yes, that turned out to be the error. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your `doInBackground()` method is not called, try calling your task like this, this is a known issue:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    new GetRoutes().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, "test");
else
    new GetRoutes().execute("test");
```

and add this to the top of the method that calls the asynk task, (eclipse will ask you to so just in case ..)

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
```

SOLUTION UPDATE:

as I saw you are implementing the adapter right after the call of the asynktask, but with this beeing asynchronous, you MUST wait for the adapter until the task has finished, generally this is beeing made on the `onPostExecute()` method, so replace your lines

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    R.layout.list_item, android.R.id.text1, values);

list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

inside `onPostExecute()`, and retry

Comment: it all seems okey, try cleaning your project

Comment: It seems that the values array still does not update.

Comment: are you sure there is no exception out there ?

Comment: I believe that I am catching the relevant Exceptions (and they should still update the array). [However, you may view my LogCat to verify.](http://pastebin.com/VEy922W1)

Comment: add an e.printStackTrace() on all your catch clauses to really be sure if there is any error,

Comment: Thanks for the tip. [Could this possibly indicate a problem with my parsing?](http://pastebin.com/BnDM023t)

Comment: [I have updated my GetRoutes method](http://pastebin.com/uGV8Jca2) and it still does not update the array.

Comment: there is a NPE
.
.
01-02 16:00:10.779: W/System.err(1361): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-02 16:00:10.779: W/System.err(1361):         at com.android.internal.os.LoggingPrintStream.println(LoggingPrintStream.java:298)

Comment: hoooold on for a sec, show the code of the asynktask call, with the implementation of the adapter for the listview, because it is asynchronous, so the adapter MUST be called after doInBackground, ie onPostExecute

Comment: [This is the code you have requested](http://pastebin.com/xte070mB), should I move the adapter?