# Android 4.0 asynctask at the same time not possible

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have the same problem [Running multiple AsyncTasks at the same time -- not possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068984/running-multiple-asynctasks-at-the-same-time-not-possible) 
except I use android 4.0 with android:minSdkVersion="14".

I tried his example, and get also :

```
bar bar bar
bar bar bar
bar bar bar
```

EDIT :

I found the solution [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#executeOnExecutor%28java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20Params...%29)

Instead of using  :

```
task.execute();
```

use :

```
task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, null);
```

Comment: Please consider adding your soulution as an answer and accept it so this question does not show up as unanswered anymore. I will upvote your answer if you do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like this explains it (from the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)):

> When first introduced, AsyncTasks were executed serially on a single background thread. Starting with DONUT, this was changed to a pool of threads allowing multiple tasks to operate in parallel. Starting with HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common application errors caused by parallel execution.
>
> If you truly want parallel execution, you can invoke executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, Object[]) with THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.

Comment: And with a code example, instead of calling `myAsyncExtendingClass().execute()`, you would call `myAsyncExtendingClass().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, "");`