# Two different AsyncTasks execute at the same time

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have two total different implementations of `AsyncTask`, lets say `AT1` and `AT2`.

`AT1` is executed first, then `AT2` is executed. `AT1` waits in `doInBackground` until `AT2` has done its task by polling this data every 500 ms. But this never happens.

So what I basically want is this:
[image]

But what seems to happen is this:
[image]
Except `AT1` is never done, and `AT2` is never started.

Is there a way I can force these two `AsyncTask`s to be executed on two seperate threads, or is there another solution for this?

It is not possible to first start `AT2` and after that execute `AT1`.

**EDIT**
For clarification: `AT1` is executed when a user opens a particular screen, and needs to download data for that screen, based on a location. `AT2` is executed on Location change, and when that happens, some calculations are made that cannot be done on the UI thread.

When `AT2` has never been executed, `AT1` has no location to download data for, so it needs to wait for `AT2` to finish. When `AT2` *has* been executed, the location data is already there, and `AT1` doesn't need to wait.

Also, this problem occurs in ICS, not in Android 2.3, like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068984/running-multiple-asynctasks-at-the-same-time-not-possible) suggests.

Comment: "AT1 waits in doInBackground until AT2 has done its task" - so no point in running asynchronously.....?

Comment: Both need to do network operations, and `AT1` is not always executed if `AT2` is executed.

Comment: However, I found this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068984/running-multiple-asynctasks-at-the-same-time-not-possible, I will investigate that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I posted this question, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068984/running-multiple-asynctasks-at-the-same-time-not-possible) appeared in the `Related` section.
It advices to use `executeOnExecutor`, I've implemented this as follows:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    new SetLocationAsyncTask().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, location);
} else {
    new SetLocationAsyncTask().execute(location);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the point of having two async tasks, if one waits for the other? And if you want to do it, why not have the first one start the second one and put the "done" stuff in the second task?

Comment: Both Asynctasks need to do network operations, so Asynctasks are needed. Furthermore, AT1 is executed on user request (open particular screen), AT2 is executed on Location change.

Comment: I agree with Barry, there must be a much simpler way of doing this, even if you use two asynctasks. I would not make one dependent of the other. But I'd need to know more about the app in order to say more.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you may need to rethink your logic - if you're kicking off a thread which then needs to wait for another thread to do some work, why not just have the first thread do that work?

If you really need 2 AsyncTasks, have the first one gather whatever data is needed and don't kick off the second until after the first is finished - have a read about onPostExecute in the docs.