# Multiple asynctasks from one Activity

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I want to get data from 3 different rest calls in a single activity. How can I do this using asynctasks. How can I co-ordinate 3 tasks?

Update: What I want to do is to wait for all the three tasks to complete before updating UI.

Comment: Although you indicate that three calls must be made, you should clarify what you mean by co-ordinate the tasks.

Comment: Do you need to issue one task, get back a response then issue the next one.  Or fire and forget until they are all returned.

Comment: CO-ORDINATE is too broad a term to use. It is ambiguous and hence I have docked a point.  Chose your words carefully, and be specific. You need to define the constraints in your questions.

Comment: Once you have done this we will render our opinions on the best options if they have not already been rendered.

Comment: The best way of handling multiple AsyncTask is to call the next AsyncTask in side the onPost() method in first AsyncTask. The reason is while you are running a background thread using AsyncTask there is a UI thread also running. So too much of load will cause to exceed the heap size which is bad.

Comment: This question may be a duplicate but not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068984/running-multiple-asynctasks-at-the-same-time-not-possible See the "Update" in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to this post

[Running multiple AsyncTasks at the same time — not possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4072832/1441666)

AsyncTask uses a thread pool pattern for running the stuff from doInBackground(). The issue is initially (in early Android OS versions) the pool size was just 1, meaning no parallel computations for a bunch of AsyncTasks. But later they fixed that and now the size is 5, so at most 5 AsyncTasks can run simultaneously. Unfortunately I don't remember in what version exactly they changed that.

Comment: From Android OS version M or above  5 AsyncTasks can run simultaneously in android.