# Post data AsyncTask won't execute android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, androidhttpclient

I have this simple code where i do post to a server some data. As this is happening on click where i call the function that starts the asyncTask like this:

```
save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    editProfile();
            }
        });
```

And here is my editProfile class:

```
private void editProfile() {
        Log.v("--", "start");
        final String newAddress = address.getText().toString();
        final String newPhone = phone.getText().toString();
        final String newEmail = email.getText().toString();
        final String newStatus = status.getText().toString();
        final String registerURL = "http://myurl/companyapp/"
                + "user.php?action=edit&user_id=" + userID + "&address="
                + newAddress + "&phone=" + newPhone + "&" + "email=" + newEmail
                + "&status=" + newStatus;
        Log.v("--", registerURL);
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(registerURL);

                // httppost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                httppost.setHeader("Accept",
                        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                // httppost.setHeader("Content-type",
                // "application/json");
                httppost.setHeader("Content-Type",
                        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(
                        5);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_id", userID
                        + ""));
                nameValuePairs
                        .add(new BasicNameValuePair("address", newAddress));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone", newPhone));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", newEmail));
                nameValuePairs
                        .add(new BasicNameValuePair("status", newStatus));

                try {
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,
                            "UTF-8"));
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    test = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                    if (test.contains("\"success\":true\"")) {
                        Toast.makeText(EditProfile.this,
                                getString(R.string.profile_updated),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        finish();
                    }
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

        }.execute();
    }
```

In logcat i can see that the function is called but the asyncTask wont start. Can anyone tell me why is this happening?

Comment: Are you sure it is not? There is no log inside `doInBackground`. AsyncTask is also single threaded per default so your task might be in the queue to be executed when you already have one running. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12159403/executing-multiple-asynctasks-parallely

Comment: @zapl it was running, the problem was in the if statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that this was running, the problem was in the `if(test.contains("\"success\":true\""))` - that if statement didn't go true so I can finish the activity