# Calling two async task at the same time

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I want to write a android app to download a image(jpg) and a json object from the server. For this, I had write two Async Task to do so. However, when i call the two tasks at the same time, only the first one is loaded and the second one do not. Can anyone explain the problem and give me some help?

Here is my piece of code:

```
public class Catalog extends Activity {
private TextView text;
private ImageButton image;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_catalog);
   // Intent intent = getIntent();

    /*RelativeLayout m_vwJokeLayout=(RelativeLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.layout1);
    LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(
               LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            TextView tv=new TextView(this);
            tv.setLayoutParams(lparams);
            tv.setText("test");
            m_vwJokeLayout.addView(tv);*/

    image = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    final String imageUrl="http://137.189.97.18/image/20000338902.jpg";

    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    String[] showcata = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.CatalogSpinner);
    ArrayAdapter <String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter <String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, showcata);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    s.setAdapter(adapter);

    s.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
            String selected = parentView.getSelectedItem().toString();
            text.setText(selected);

            //text.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Blue));
            /*RelativeLayout m_vwJokeLayout=(RelativeLayout) Catalog.this.findViewById(R.id.layout1);
            LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            TextView tv=new TextView(Catalog.this);
            tv.setLayoutParams(lparams);
            tv.setText(selected);
            m_vwJokeLayout.addView(tv);*/

            //AsyncTask myTask = new httpconnect(Catalog.this);

            Catalog.httpconnect myTask = new httpconnect(Catalog.this);
            myTask.execute("123");

            Catalog.downloadimage download = new downloadimage(Catalog.this);
            download.execute(imageUrl);
    /*if(selected.equals("Pants"))
        text.setText("RIGHT");*/
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
            // your code here
        }

    });

}

public static class httpconnect extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
    public Catalog myActivity;
    public httpconnect(Catalog a)
    {
        myActivity = a;
    }

protected void onPreExecute(){
 //text.setText("load");
}

protected String doInBackground(String... x){
    String result = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    StringBuilder sb=null;

    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://137.189.97.18/main2.php");
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("_method", "post"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("catagory", x[0]));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();

    }catch(Exception e){

        Log.d("HTTP response error",e.toString());
    }


    try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");

        String line="0";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result=sb.toString();

    }catch(Exception e){
    }
    return result;

}

protected void onProgressUpdate(){

}

protected void onPostExecute(String z){
    //text.setText(z);
    Log.d("BAC", z);
    myActivity.text.setText(z);

    String product_id = null;
    String colour_id = null;
    String colour= null;
    String picture= null;

        JSONObject json_data;
        try {
            json_data = new JSONObject(z.trim());
            product_id=json_data.getString("product_id");
            colour_id=json_data.getString("price");
            colour=json_data.getString("colour");
            picture=json_data.getString("picture");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            JSONArray jArray;
            try {
                jArray = new JSONArray(z.trim());
                 JSONObject json_data2=null;
                    for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                            json_data2 = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            product_id=json_data2.getString("product_id");
                            colour_id=json_data2.getString("colour_id");
                            colour=json_data2.getString("colour");
                            picture=json_data2.getString("picture");
                    }
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            //e.printStackTrace();
        }


    TextView text2 = (TextView) myActivity.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    myActivity.text.setText(product_id);
    text2.setText(colour_id);

}
}

public static class downloadimage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>{
    public Catalog myActivity;
    public downloadimage(Catalog a)
    {
        myActivity = a;
    }

protected void onPreExecute(){
 //text.setText("load");
}

protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... x){
    Bitmap bmImg = null;
    URL myFileUrl =null; 
    try {
    myFileUrl= new URL(x[0]);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
    HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection)myFileUrl.openConnection();
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.connect();
    int length = conn.getContentLength();
    int[] bitmapData =new int[length];
    byte[] bitmapData2 =new byte[length];
    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

    bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

    } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bmImg;


}

protected void onProgressUpdate(){

}

protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap z){
    //text.setText(z);
    //Log.d("image", z);

    myActivity.image.setImageBitmap(z);
}
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_catalog, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068984/running-multiple-asynctasks-at-the-same-time-not-possible

Comment: when i just call the second async task (imagedownload), the result i got is also the same as the first one, whick also get a json reply. Why is it the case ??

Comment: try to not passing Catalog class as parameter of the asynctask class, it is safe to update imageview & textview from both asynctask class, since both of them is inner class

Comment: that means it is no need to pass Catalog as a value to the task to update the UI??

Comment: i had tried your suggestion, but it does not solve the problem. It still run the httpconnect Async task instead of the imagedownload task...

Comment: problem solove. It is problem of eclipse, it cannot run the updated program. It works well after restart.

Comment: Running multiple AsyncTasks at the same time [**check this answer.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068984/running-multiple-asynctasks-at-the-same-time-not-possible/13800208#13800208)