# Creating Multiple AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask, id3

I am using an external library for my android project. With that library i am getting the ID3 tags from stream Mp3 url. The code uses URLConnection to reach the link and then gets the tag informations.But the problem is its a very slow procedure.

while doing it on a main thread it takes more than  2 minutes to get ID3 tags of 25 songs from their URLs. So i decided to use multiple AsyncTasks to make the process faster and i used this code below. It became faster a bit, but still few seconds below 2 minute mark. When i checked the Threads tab from DDMS and i saw that during the runtime, there is only 6 AsyncTask is created and running.

My question is , how can i increase the number of AsyncTask running , in this loop.

```
counter=0;
for (final SongDetail e : songs) {

  new AsyncTask<Void , Void, Void>() {


  @Override
  protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

    try {

       MP3 mp3 = new MP3(e.getLink());
       e.setTitle(mp3.getTitle());
       e.setArtist(mp3.getBand());
    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
          e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e2) {
          e2.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
    }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
   counter++;

   if(counter==songs.size()) {
      Log.d("KA","loop finished");

     }
  }

 }.execute();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The Android OS will decide how many parallel threads can be running at any given time. Just because you start 20 of them doesn't mean they'll all run. Android OS will queue them up and will run some of them at a time.

See this answer for more details:
[Running multiple AsyncTasks at the same time -- not possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068984/running-multiple-asynctasks-at-the-same-time-not-possible)