# Choose between different implementations of the same class

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-compatibility

I am not sure if this is possible or if I am thinking of this correctly.

In the Android developer training for [Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html), a custom version of the `AsyncTask` is used to make the code compatible with android versions below `HONEYCOMB`.

This great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4072832/1386784) explains the differences between `AsyncTask` operation in pre and post `HONEYCOMB`. The reason that a custom version is supplied in the guide is that the default in pre `HONEYCOMB` (a pool of tasks) will very easily crash with a `java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException` if the `GridView` of images is scrolled quickly. For this scenario, the default post `HONEYCOMB` version (serial execution on an additional thread) is what is required.

I could easily do this by using a newer version of `AsyncTask` in my project (like done in the developer training example) but this is not very compatible with future changes.

**What I would like to do is the following:**

> If the version is `HONEYCOMB` or greater, use the implementation of
>   `AsyncTask` provided in the framework, whereas if it is earlier, use
>   the `AsyncTask` implementation provided in my application.

Is this possible (and how) or should I be thinking about it differently?

**EDIT:**
I understand how to provide conditionals based on the running `SDK_VERSION`.

The issue I have is that `AsyncTask` is an abstract class, meaning that I have to provide an implementation.
E.g. I have a `AsyncTask` called `myTask` which extends `AsyncTask` like below:

```
public class myTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    // Implementations for the abstract functions (doInBackground)
}
```

How do I decide which version of the `AsyncTask` is extended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11){ // Honeycomb
{
  AsyncTask taskObj = new DefaultAsyncTaskImpl();
  taskObj.execute();  
} else {
  AsyncTask taskObj = new CustomAsyncTaskImpl();
  taskObj.execute();
}
```

And in your code define both classes in which the first extends `AsyncTask` and the second is your own implementation

Note: `SDK_INT` available in API 4+

**Edit:**

You can use `factory design pattern` to decide which object to create based on the SDK version.

Comment: See edit. That suggests what I am fearing, providing separate implementations for every `AsyncTask` class in my entire application. Also, won't that code sample return two different Objects so all code would have to handle cases for different object types?

Comment: *for every custom `AsyncTask` class (like `myTask`) is what I meant

Comment: You can use `Factory design pattern` to decide which object to create based on the SDK version.

Comment: Thanks! The `Factory design pattern` is exactly what I am looking for.  If at all possible could you please include that in the answer so other people can find it if they are looking? Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            // Use built in AysncTask
        } else {
            // Use your AsyncTask
        }
```

you need to check the OS version