# Fragment Tab providing slow response

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I use the v4 support lib for `FragmentTabHost`.

The requirement is that when I'm switching tab one to another & another to one every time in fragment

`onCreateView()` & `onActivityCreated()` is calling. that's why my code performance is slow.

So, any other solutions? how to increase performance in `fragment` tab?

Comment: The only way oncreateview and onactivitycreate will create performance problems is if you are performing heaving tasks in there

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fragmenttabhost performance is slow?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15500331/fragmenttabhost-performance-is-slow)