# AsyncTask hangs on at beginning

Tags: android, android-asynctask

`AsyncTask` works fine in Android 4.x, but not for Android 2.3.6. I've step-by-step debugged Android 2.3.6 with a physical mobile device.

It hangs on here:

```
myTask = new GetDataFromServer();
```

`GetDataFromServer` is the class of `AsyncTask`.

What's going on?

Here under is my code, I only used 1 AsyncTask in my code and received messages from server.
that's all.

```
class GetDataFromServer extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{

    protected void onPreExecute ()
    {

        progressDialog1=ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Loading data", "Please wait...",true);
    }
    protected String doInBackground(String... params)
    {

        String resulttxt="";
        try {

            serverIp = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.123");


            int serverPort=31000;


            Socket clientSocket=new Socket(serverIp,serverPort);

            BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));
            bw.write(params[0]);
            bw.flush();


            BufferedReader  br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));


            resulttxt=br.readLine();
            if(resulttxt.contains("OK"))
            {
                publishProgress(resulttxt);

            }
            else
            {
                publishProgress(resulttxt);
                clientSocket.close(); 
                bw.close();
                br.close();
                return null;

            }
            resulttxt="";
            resulttxt=br.readLine();
            resulttxt=resulttxt.trim();


            clientSocket.close(); 

        } catch (IOException e) {

            if(Status_txt!=null)
                Status_txt.append( "Server is done.");
        }
        catch (NetworkOnMainThreadException e){
            if(Status_txt!=null)
                Status_txt.append( "NetworkOnMainThreadException");
        }

        return resulttxt;


    }
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String...inStr){

        String[] strData=inStr[0].split("_");
        String szTemp="Last Purchase Date: ";


        szTemp+=strData[1];

        szTemp+="  ,Valid days: ";
        szTemp+=strData[2];
        //Status_txt.setText(szTemp);
        if(Status_txt!=null)
            Status_txt.setText("You Are The Super User");

    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String data) {
        tl_prediction2.removeAllViews();


        if (data == null)
        {

        }
        else {


            if((data.contains("#")==true) || (data.contains("*")==true) 
                    ||data.contains("&")==true)
            {




                String[] arrayTmp=data.split("#");
                for(Integer i=0;i<arrayTmp.length;i++)
                {
                    String[] SubArrayTmp=arrayTmp[i].split("_");

                    tl_prediction2.addView(generateRow(4,SubArrayTmp));

                }
            }

        }
        progressDialog1.dismiss();
    }

};
```

Comment: You have to also post code of your GetDataFromServer class.

Comment: Post the logcat stacktrace

Answer (score 2):

Since you haven't posted any code, I could only give you some random probable solutions:

1. May be your AsyncTask is taking a lot of time to download. Trying increasing its priority using `android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(9)` inside `doInBackground()`
2. Check if you have other previous running long AsyncTask in your code. AsyncTask by default operates on a single background thread. That means your AsyncTask task wouldn't be executed unless your previous AsyncTask are done. To allow parallel execution use `executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, params)`. You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068984/running-multiple-asynctasks-at-the-same-time-not-possible)
3. Check for Internet and other permissions in Manifest. This is mostly where people make mistake.

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask works with ThreadPool. If there too many synctasks are executing, the later AsyncTask will be blocked by others. I think you can use the thread tool in DDMS to check the How many ayncTasks are executing.

Comment: there is only one asynctask that I used. could it be the Android's version??

Comment: hanged on the new GetDataFromServer()? Add some log in onPreExecute() and doInBackground()