# Android async task to wait for other task to complete

Tags: android, concurrency, android-asynctask

I have two asyc task both perform separate network operation.I want one async task to wait for other task to finish for a single variable..I thought of doing it like perform other asyc operation onPostexecute of first one but for a single variable i have to make other task to wait first one to finish...is there any to achieve efficently
[image]

Comment: your thought was correct. have your tried that.?

Comment: Now my implementation is like that only but...i have to postponed a big task for single variable

Comment: take a look at the picture i meant that way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4072832/2191256), you can not use .execute() so;

First you have to start your tasks like this:

```
// Start first task
new Task1().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, "");
// Start second task
new Task2().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, "");
```

and then you can make a static variable so the both of tasks can access to it:

```
public static boolean task1Finished = false;
```

Then simple example of the tasks:

First task

```
private class Task1 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        Log.d("myApp", "Task1 started");

        for(int x = 0; x < 10; ++x)
        {
            try 
            {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                //Log.d("myApp", "sleeped 1000 ms");
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // Lets the second task to know that first has finished
        task1Finished = true;
    }
}
```

Second task

```
private class Task2 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        Log.d("myApp", "Task2 started");
        while( task1Finished == false )
        {
            try 
            {
                Log.d("myApp", "Waiting for Task1");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        Log.d("myApp", "Task1 finished");
        // Do what ever you like
        // ...
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.d("myApp", "All done here (Task2)");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe asynctask is not the best tool? There are some interesting classes in the android api that can help doing specifically the synchronizing job :

Quote from android developper : "Four classes aid common special-purpose synchronization idioms.

- Semaphore is a classic concurrency tool.
- CountDownLatch is a very simple yet very common utility for blocking until a given number of signals, events, or conditions hold.
- A CyclicBarrier is a resettable multiway synchronization point useful in some styles of parallel programming.
- An Exchanger allows two threads to exchange objects at a rendezvous point, and is useful in several pipeline designs."

So I suggest looking into :

Cyclic Barrier
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html

Exchanger 
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Exchanger.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to create another async in OnpostExecute of first one if you need to call the other synchronously.