# Why in Android Async task not working as it supposed to Do

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an activity, this is the `splash activity`, I want to load 2 music in it and when the loading is finish I want to start my welcome page, unfortunately I made something wrong.

Even though I got the `log` which I made when the load is complete , but I also got the log when the 2 music are not loaded..

#### Log

```
Loaded 1 true
Loaded 2 true
1 not two
2 not two
```

#### code

```
package com.Syriatel.EatTel;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.SoundPool;
import android.media.SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class Splash extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        new Load1().execute(1);
        new Load2().execute(2);
    }

    public int soundID, soundID2;

    private SoundPool soundPool1, soundPool2;
    boolean isLoad1, isLoad2;

    class Load2 extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Integer> {

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (isLoad1 && isLoad2) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this, Welcome.class);
                finish();
                startActivity(intent);
            }else{
                Log.e("2", "not two");
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            soundPool2 = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
            soundPool2.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId,
                        int status) {
                    isLoad2 = true;
                    Log.e("Loaded 2", "true");
                }
            });
            soundID2 = soundPool2.load(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.select, 1);
            return 1;
        }

    }

    class Load1 extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Integer> {

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (isLoad1 && isLoad2) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this, Welcome.class);
                finish();
                startActivity(intent);
            }else{
                Log.e("1", "not two");
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            soundPool1 = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
            soundPool1.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId,
                        int status) {
                    isLoad1 = true;
                    Log.e("Loaded 1", "true");
                }
            });
            soundID = soundPool1.load(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.thip, 1);
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would always play the music in a background service. Send an Intent to start the music and another to stop it. Or use a bounded service and send messages through Messengers/Handlers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating a separate thread from within each `Asynctask`. When you call

```
soundID = soundPool1.load(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.thip, 1);
```

a separate thread starts loading the music. However, the `AsyncTask` will continue in its thread, complete `doInBackground`, go to `onPostexecute` and when it gets there neither of the flags will be set because `soundPool1.load()` and soundPool2.load()` are *still running*.

Your code is executing exactly as one would expect!

To solve this, using your code structure, you need to add some code to *both* `doInBackground` methods. Here is number 2 updated:

```
protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... params) {
    soundPool2 = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    soundPool2.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId, int status) {
            isLoad2 = true;
            Log.e("Loaded 2", "true");
        }
    });
    soundID2 = soundPool2.load(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.select, 1);

    // New Code so we wait until the load is complete
    while(isLoad2 == false) {
        Thread.sleep(1000); // 1 second (change as you feel fit)
    }
```

Then it will only get to `onPostExecute` when the music has actually loaded. It would also be wise to make sure you initialise the flags, so in each AsyncTask:

```
@override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    isLoadX = false
}
```

If you are planning a lot of AsyncTasks, you should read [this](http://foo.jasonhudgins.com/2010/05/limitations-of-asynctask.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068984/running-multiple-asynctasks-at-the-same-time-not-possible).

Comment: what is the solution please?

Comment: I didnt get the solution, did you mean the i have to put the while in the inbackground of the both asynctask ?

Comment: Thanks you very much. it works, you such a great coder, thanks

Comment: I would set it at just over a typical time for the music to load.

Answer (score 1):

Remove following code from your onCreate() and put on PostExecute() of load1

```
new Load2().execute(2);
```

and write launch your welcome activity in PostExecute() of load2.

Answer (score 0):

Sth wrong about logic in here. You've started 2 simulate jobs. And in each jobs you ask for loaded statues of both.

```
if (isLoad1 && isLoad2) {

}else{

}
```

My solution is that you could create 3rd thread. Check for loaded statuses of both. If it's not ready then sleep and recheck again. Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like it is quite likely both async tasks are running correctly, but because you can't predict which order they finish you cant predict that both flags will be set in the postexecute, in fact it is quite likely they wont be. This will result in both async tasks failing to start your intent. Additionally you might want to add the volatile modifier to the boolean flags to ensure the "freshest" value is always used.  Actually looking at your code, I don't think you really want to use two async tasks...