# Is it possible to run multiple AsyncTask in same time?

Tags: android

I've two activities in my application. In my Activity A I'm using one AsyncTask and second Activity B also using another one AsyncTask. In my Activity A I've upload some data to server and in my Activity B I'm trying to download some other data from server. Both these are running in AsyncTask. My problem is when I trying to download data from server in Activity B `onPreExecute()` method was called but `doInBackground()` method was not called it is waiting up to the first Activity A's `doInBackground()` action finished. Why it is happened? Is it possible to run more than one background actions at a same time..

**In Activity A**

```
ImageButton submit_button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.submit_button);

submit_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View record_button) 
        {
                       new Save_data().execute();
        }
       });
class Save_data extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Integer> 
 {
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {

}
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... arg0) 
{
     //uploading data here
    }

 }
```

**In my Activity B**

```
ImageButton get_button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.get_button);
    get_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View record_button) 
            {
                           new download_process().execute();
            }
           });
    class download_process extends AsyncTask<String, integer, integer>
     {
        protected void onPreExecute() 
        {
       Log.e("pre-execute","has been called");//This Log works well
    }
         protected Integer doInBackground(String... arg0) 
    {
         //downloading data here
        }   
     }
```

Comment: how to use executor .. please tell me ..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running multiple AsyncTasks at the same time -- not possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068984/running-multiple-asynctasks-at-the-same-time-not-possible) - which provides a really good explanation

Answer (score 25, accepted):

use executor as follows

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    new Save_data().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, location);
} else {
    new Save_data().execute(location);
}
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13800208/1051147)

Comment: What is the location here ?

Comment: apply   it where  you call execute()

Answer (score 17):

Yes, it is, but since Honeycomb, there's a change in the way `AsyncTask` is handled on Android. From HC+ they are executed sequentially, instead of being fired in parallel, as it used to be. Solution for this is to run `AsyncTask` using `THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR` executor explicitely. You can create helper class for that:

```
public class AsyncTaskTools {
    public static <P, T extends AsyncTask<P, ?, ?>> void execute(T task) {
        execute(task, (P[]) null);
    }
    
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public static <P, T extends AsyncTask<P, ?, ?>> void execute(T task, P... params) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, params);
        } else {
            task.execute(params);
        }
    }
}
```

and then you can simply call:

```
AsyncTaskTools.execute( new MyAsyncTask() );
```

or with params (however I rather suggest passign params via task constructor):

```
AsyncTaskTools.execute( new MyAsyncTask(), <your params here> );
```

Comment: I got this message "The method executeAsyncTask(T, P[]) is undefined for the type AsyncTasktools" Why ?

Comment: Fixed. But it was quite basic bug, why you did not try to fix yourself? :)

Comment: Inner classes cannot have static declarations!

Comment: @LucaZiegler thanks for downvote. But where do you see inner class exactlty?