# Is it possible to create multiple AsyncTask at same time?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am creating Download Manager in which I want to download multiple files at the same time and update the progress for each download. I used following line to execute AsyncTask

```
executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,Utility.KEY_DOWNLOAD_PATH);
```

But it doesn't starts multiple AsyncTask. When I click on next download it stops first and starts new download.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I think onProgressUpdate() you can call another AsyncTask.How can you call many asyncTask at atime

Comment: on clicking on listItem i can call asyncTask. But it stops the previous one and starts new task

Comment: please see below link:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068984/running-multiple-asynctasks-at-the-same-time-not-possible][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068984/running-multiple-asynctasks-at-the-same-time-not-possible

Comment: Show code where you start asyncTask.

Comment: Just go here http://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/index.html

Comment: I starts asyncTask from listItemClicklistener. // Click event for single list row
  list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
     int position, long id) {
    Toast.makeText(activity, "List Item Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
      .show();
fileDownloader.executeOnExecutor(
      AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,
      Utility.KEY_DOWNLOAD_PATH);

Comment: Take a hint from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068984/running-multiple-asynctasks-at-the-same-time-not-possible

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to run two AsyncTask in same time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18357641/is-it-possible-to-run-two-asynctask-in-same-time)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use multiple thread to run the different different services on one activity.

Comment: Yes, it is another option to handle it. But I want to know that can it be possible with asyncTask?

Comment: list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {fileDownloader.executeOnExecutor(
      AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,
      MidnightUtility.KEY_DOWNLOAD_PATH);
   }

Comment: @unflagged.destination according to your scenario which is mention above you have to use multiple thread for multiple download load service.

Answer (score 0):

Create object inside the loop.

```
void stratTask(){
    for(String url:urls){
    AsyncTask asyncTask=new AsyncTask();
     if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){

            asyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, url);
      }
      else{
            asyncTask.execute(url);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using the same code but it stops the current task and starts the new task.

Comment: I changed the answer now try this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem is in how you define fileDownloader:

```
 // Click event for single list row 
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
 @Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
 Toast.makeText(activity, "List Item Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG) .show(); 
fileDownloader.executeOnExecutor( AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, Utility.KEY_DOWNLOAD_PATH);
```

You appear to be defining the fileDownoader outside of the onclick event. So you actually only have one AsyncTask, and when execute fileDownloader.executeOnExecuter you are overwriting and previous AsyncTask assigned to that object.

You may want to change your FileDownloader class so that it contains some list of single AsyncTasks ( List ) instead, although that is not the only way to implement what you are looking for.