# calling AsyncTask in main thread inside a for loop

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I have **someclass** which do large network operations and it do take some time to complete,and hence i put it in `AsyncTask` .I have to do this process 'n' times so in the main thread using a `for` loop i called this **asynctask** n times.will it throw any error since there is an interrupt in completing the for loop.?

```
// inside main thread 
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
 new asynctask().execute(new someclass());
}
```

Comment: don't try this... run your loop into the asynctask..

Comment: i have to change a lot of methods if it wont work ,are you sure it wont work ?

Comment: What do you mean "there is an interrupt in completing the for loop"?

Comment: it takes time,thats what i mean..

Comment: How can there be a timeout in for loop if its async?

Comment: the loop is in main thread .i think i need to put it in asysnctask postexecute..

Comment: Yes, u need to handle the timeout exception only when you seek Result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running mutliple `AsyncTask` is not recommended, but if it is few times, then it will work but all async task will run serially not in parallel. But if you want async tasks to run parallelly then you can call it's `executeOnExecutor(..)` method where you have to pass `THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR` as parameter. You can search on google you can find many links. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18357641/is-it-possible-to-run-two-asynctask-in-same-time) is an example for your help.

Comment: okke let me try and if it dnt work,ill do as you said..thanks

Answer (score -1):

don't call AsyncTask n times just put your for loop in onPostExecute() and do any task up to n times

```
    private class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {



      @Override
      protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

       } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
       return resp;
      }


      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
       // execution of result of Long time consuming operation

   for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
    //do your operation here
    }

      }


      @Override
      protected void onPreExecute() {
       // Things to be done before execution of long running operation. For
       // example showing ProgessDialog
      }


      @Override
      protected void onProgressUpdate(String... text) {

       // Things to be done while execution of long running operation is in
       // progress. For example updating ProgessDialog



      }
     }
    }
```