# Running multiple AsyncTask exits the application without showing any specific error

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-camera, jakarta-mail

I have a very simple task to do in my application.I am trying to achieve the following in my application.

1.Capturing image using Custom `Camera` class when `hardware` `volume` button is pressed.And once capturing started, it should automatically capture images at a regular interval(lets say 2 sec).

2.Each images had to be saved in SD card and Mail to the corresponding Mail Id in the background.

In order to achieve the above I created a Custom `Camera Class` and `override` the hardware `volume` button to capture picture.And to send mail in the background I used Java Mail API.

As I have to send Mail at each 2 sec of interval, I wrote the Mailing and Saving to SD Card code using `AsyncTask`. I find out that from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4072832/1665507) and from some other posts too that the pool size of `AsyncTask` is Max 128+10=138 total.As I am sending mail at 2 sec interval,it exceed the max pool size which results the error.

But my requirement is to capture High resolution images at 2 sec interval and mail it to the corresponding Mail Id.

Is is possible using `AsyncTask`? or any other Framework android provides to execute long running tasks?

Below is what I have tried so far,

**Hardware Volume key override**

```
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
        { 
           if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) { 

                timer = new Timer();
                TimerTask updateProfile = new CustomTimerTask(DVCameraActivity.this);
                timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(updateProfile, 0, 2000);
                Toast toast= Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Picture Capturing Started..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
                toast.show();
           return true;
       } else {
           return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); 
       }
    }
```

**CustomTimerTask**

```
public class CustomTimerTask extends TimerTask {
        public CustomTimerTask(Context con) {
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
             if (isCamera == true)
                mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
        }

    }
```

**PictureCallback**

```
PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            new SavePhotoTask().execute(data);
             if (mCamera!= null)
            camera.startPreview();
        }

    };
```

**SavePhotoTask()**

```
class SavePhotoTask extends AsyncTask<byte[], String, String> {
        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(byte[]... jpeg) {


            File mediaStorageDir = new File(
                    Environment
                            .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                    "Secret Camera");

            if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
                if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                    Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
                    return null;
                }
            }

            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
                    .format(new Date());
            File mediaFile;
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                    + "IMG_" + timeStamp + "." + mSuffix);
            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(mediaFile);
                fos.write(jpeg[0]);
                fos.close();

                path=mediaFile.getAbsolutePath();
                SendMail(path);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            } catch (IOException e) {
            }

            return mediaFile.toString();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);


        }


    }
```

**SendMail()**

```
private void SendMail(String Imagepath) {
        Mail m = new Mail(Constants.email, Constants.psw);
        String[] toArr = { Constants.email };
        m.setTo(toArr);
        m.setFrom("<EMAIL>");
        m.setSubject("Spy Camera Images");
        m.setBody("If you are watching the image, then my Spy Camera App is working..Voila!!");
        try {
            m.addAttachment(Imagepath);
            if (m.send()) {
                Log.i("MAIL SEND", "SUCCESSS");
                Send=true;
            } else {
                Send=false;
                Log.i("MAIL SEND", "FAILED");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("MailApp", "Could not send email", e);
        }
    }
```

**Logcat Error**

```
08-23 18:37:55.609: I/dalvikvm(12540): DALVIK THREADS:
08-23 18:37:55.609: I/dalvikvm(12540): "main" prio=5 tid=1 WAIT
08-23 18:37:55.609: I/dalvikvm(12540):   | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x401b8968 self=0xcd38
08-23 18:37:55.609: I/dalvikvm(12540):   | sysTid=12540 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=-1345017816
08-23 18:37:55.609: I/dalvikvm(12540):   at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
08-23 18:37:55.609: I/dalvikvm(12540):   - waiting on <0x48718010> (a android.os.MessageQueue)
08-23 18:37:55.609: I/dalvikvm(12540):   at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:288)
08-23 18:37:55.617: I/dalvikvm(12540):   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:146)
08-23 18:37:55.617: I/dalvikvm(12540):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:110)
08-23 18:37:55.624: I/dalvikvm(12540):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4632)
08-23 18:37:55.624: I/dalvikvm(12540):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-23 18:37:55.624: I/dalvikvm(12540):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-23 18:37:55.624: I/dalvikvm(12540):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:871)
08-23 18:37:55.624: I/dalvikvm(12540):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
08-23 18:37:55.624: I/dalvikvm(12540):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-23 18:37:55.624: I/dalvikvm(12540): "AsyncTask #34" prio=5 tid=42 MONITOR
```

Sorry for such a lengthy explanation. I couldn't find a shorter way to explain my problem. Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own queue of requests, put each "send picture" request in the queue, and use one mail task to process requests from the queue.  Use a single connection to send all requests from the queue until the queue is empty, then close the connection and wait for the next request.

Comment: Your answer looks promising but could you please give me some reference links which will help me to achieve this?

Comment: Look at java.util.Queue, the classes that implement it, and the subinterface BlockingQueue.  Examples of those classes should get you started.