# is it possible to run multiple AsyncTasks parallel in below API 13 devices?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am working on a project which uses multiple `Asynctasks` and I want all the tasks should run parallel.As of API 13, Android provides `AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(Executor exec, Params... params)` method for parallel execution.But I have to do the project for all API levels.Is it possible to run parallel executions in lower versions using `AsynTask` or some other framework?

Comment: You can of course, but keep in mind that several async task means that the CPU will be more used. And also Async taks are now executed serial. You can force the "parallel mode" but it is not adviced since lots of android phone have single core CPU.

Comment: What are you using asynctask for ?

Comment: I am using it to send mail in every 2 sec using Java Mail API. Could you please give some reference link to achieve this?

Comment: [See this to answer your question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068984/running-multiple-asynctasks-at-the-same-time-not-possible

Comment: Java mail App is not easy going.. For the every 2 sec part i suggest you use a Service