# How can I make my multi AsycTask works

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Here is my execution:

```
KlientNameValue kn = new KlientNameValue(getApplicationContext());
            ZamowienieNameValue zn = new ZamowienieNameValue(getApplicationContext());

            kn.new MyAsyncTask().execute(zam.klient.getNazwa(),zam.klient.getNip(),zam.klient.getAdres());
            zn.new MyAsyncTask().execute(zam.getSuma());
            for (int i = 0; i < MainActivity.lista_wybranych_towarow.size(); i++) {
                TowarZamowienieName tzn = new TowarZamowienieName(getApplicationContext());
                tzn.new MyAsyncTask().execute(String.valueOf(MainActivity.valueYouWant),String.valueOf(MainActivity.lista_wybranych_towarow.get(i).getTow_id()),MainActivity.lista_wybranych_towarow.get(i).getTow_ilosc());
            }
```

For one execution it works but for two or more don't what should I do ? I want to add they all have to be executed while on click has place.

Comment: What's the problem with that code?

Comment: @m0skit0 only the first execution took place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This overuse of AsyncTask is really a code smell. I guess that your problem is that your Asynctasks don't get executed in paralel. To execute in paralel on API > 11 use:

`new MyAsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, PARAMS);`

Or even better use a version of this function:

```
if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ) {
    new MyAsyncTask().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
} else {
    new MyAsyncTask().execute();
}
```

More in depth explanation:

[Running multiple AsyncTasks at the same time -- not possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068984/running-multiple-asynctasks-at-the-same-time-not-possible?lq=1)

Comment: Do you really need so many tasks runnning in parallel? It seems that mannaging them will be a nightmare. Are you sure you can't get away with only using one AsyncTask that calls the same function on different params?

Comment: @V M this is priceless suggestion ! I will make it as you say. Thank you very much