# Need advice to AsyncTask Object creation

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I need to fetch data from the Server.

So I chosen Asysntask class to send my HTTP request .

Below is the template of my Code:

```
clss A{

 new B().getDataFromServer();  //This method will be called several times.
}

class B{
public String getDataFromServer(){

Task task = new Task();
task.execute();

}

class Task extends AysncTask{
   //async task stuff here
}

}
```

Now my question is, I am craeting **Task task = new Task()** object many times.
The above step will cause perfomance issue.??
Please let me know if ther's any other simple or less memory consumption way to do this.

Comment: seems you are looking for it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068984/running-multiple-asynctasks-at-the-same-time-not-possible

Answer (score 0):

Asynchronous task run now sequentially from HoneyComb, If you really need to run the `AsynTask` parallely then use `executeOnExecutor` which run the task parallel and optimize the CPU very well.