# Android AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR vs custom ThreadPool with Runnables

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask, threadpool

I have some tasks that I need to process concurrently on Android and I would like to use some sort of a thread pool to do so. I couldn't find in the documentation what actually happens "behind the scenes" when executing an AsyncTask with AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.

My question is: What do I lose by using AsyncTasks with AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR as opposed to implementing a custom ThreadPool with Runnables? (Let's talk post-honeycomb).

I realize the question is rather general, but I'm fairly new to doing concurrent programming (besides AsyncTask itself). I'm not looking for a tutorial on concurrent programming! I only seek to understand how the Android specific AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR is different. I think an explanation would be helpful for others in the future as they weigh the pros and cons of choosing to use AsyncTask vs Thread/Runnable. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4072832/1426565

Comment: @Guardanis, update 2 of that answer is exactly what I was looking for, thanks. I don't think I would have found that one on my own. Now I understand the limitations of AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AsyncTasks provide you with possibility to execute actions on UI thread before and after executing worker task. So, if you dont need communicating with UI then use your own executor - you can always implement this using handler. AsyncTasks are being executed serially since api 11 because parallel execution was considered to difficult to properly implement.

If you need more flexibility, then executors are a way to go, they will allow you to freely specify how many tasks to execute in parallel, how many to put in queue etc.

If you are interested in details, you can always look into sources:

http://androidxref.com/4.4.3_r1.1/xref/development/samples/training/bitmapfun/BitmapFun/src/main/java/com/example/android/bitmapfun/util/AsyncTask.java

Answer (score 0):

Non-UI work might be taken by anything including AsyncTasks, HandlerThreads, IntentServices etc.

The reason it's suggested AsyncTasks for UI-related works (works that affect UI) is that AsyncTask has helper callbacks that lets you to transfer the control to the UI thread.

However, it's not suggested for longer running operations since it's, by default, uses a global executor and this may cause app-global waiting threads to be stalled while executing long-runnings ops. So you can switch to a custom executor and get rid of global affect.

At the end of the day, HandlerThreads are threads again that gives a Looper to keep the thread alive. Executions will still be done in serial so what's the real reason to use them ? I believe it's the power of ability to execute Runnables like Executors but more in light-weight fashion.

IntentServices are again - the way to execute tasks serially but you've more power and isolation since they're entirely different components has seperate lifecycles. They automatically destroyed so you don't have to worry about destroying them to reduce your app process priority ( off the topic but causes some memory performance problems, trashing etc. )