# How to run multiple background tasks in parallel using AsyncTask in android..?

Tags: android

I am a beginner in android development. I ve already tried using simple execute() to do 1 task and it worked well. But i have now come across a problem where i need to perform 3-4 tasks concurrently in background using AsyncTask. I have seen several questions on this but i dint get to see a code for doing the same. I think executeOnExecutor() is the answer to my question but i want to see an example of it. Can someone please explain me with a simple example of how to run say 2 tasks concurrently using AsyncTask ?

Comment: The [documentation for this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) seems relatively straightforward.  What prevents you from simply doing it more than once?

Answer (score 3):

The [docs for AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) cover this. By default, all of the AsyncTasks happen on a single thread. To use multiple threads, you need to use a different executor. AsyncTask has a thread pool executor you can use:

`task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, params);`

Answer (score -1):

I would strongly recommend not using multiple Async tasks. I did that before and ran into a ton of issues. [See this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068984/running-multiple-asynctasks-at-the-same-time-not-possible). What happens is one Async Task will wait for the other to finish before starting. Try using a runnable:

```
Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Code
    }
};
new Thread(myRunnable).start();
```