# "Attempted read on closed stream" when trying to use two AsynTasks in same time on 2.3

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have 2 different `AsyncTask`. I trying to execute it in same time. On 4.0+ Android it works fine.

But on 2.3 one of this Task always throw exception "Error converting result: java.io.IOException: Attempted read on closed stream" when i trying to parse response from server.

If i remove execution of one of this Tasks i don't have this error.

I don't understand, is it problem only on 2.3 and i should wait for the end of 1st task to execute second task? Or something else?

This problem only on 2.3 Android, so i don't think that problem is in my Task code, so mb it just restriction of OS?

Comment: You should check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068984/running-multiple-asynctasks-at-the-same-time-not-possible)

Comment: @Marcus i tried to use this decision http://stackoverflow.com/a/13800208/1991579  from answer. But still have same error on 2.3 =/