# ANDROID: Running mutiple async tasks after the first one finishes

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-asynctask

Basically title. I can run them all in a row or all at once. I need the first one to run to load data for the rest.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have a look on it.There is a lot of detail related your problem.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068984/running-multiple-asynctasks-at-the-same-time-not-possible

Comment: execute remaining `AsyncTasks` after `onPostExecute` on first one

Comment: you can pass callback interface to AsyncTask and run remaining tasks on callback if you care about your code to be clean

Answer (score 0):

Maybes using handler for the first one so that the code runs on a different thread and trigger the rest when that one completes:

```
Handler firstTask = new Handler(new Runnable() {
    Run() {
        //do code
        //run rest of tasks
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your AsyncTasks will be run in the order in which they are submitted and **not concurrently**, unless you explicitly use the `ExecuteOnExecutor` method.  You can pass data between them accordingly.

Just to be clear, you don't have to do anything at all to make sure that the first task completes before the second (and so on) are run.  Each will complete before the next is started, in submission order.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure that the first AsyncTask has finished and returned the required data before the rest are executed, then override the onPostExecute() method of the first AsyncTask and execute the remaining AsyncTasks inside it.

onPostExecute() is a methode called after the AsyncTask is finished, you can check for the correctness of the received data inside it before executing the other AsyncTasks also inside it.