# If I have multiple AsyncTasks lined up, will the first one complete first?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

Example I have a layout with a list and an image at the top of the list. I have CursorAdapters for both of them that load this data from a service. Since android has one UI thread and all the other background AsyncTasks run on one thread, does that mean whichever one I call first, finishes first?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068984/running-multiple-asynctasks-at-the-same-time-not-possible)

Answer (score 2):

Yes it does. By default `AsyncTask`s go to one queue because they use serial executor. If you want them to execute in parallel you should use your own `ThreadPoolExecutor` instead.

Comment: Assuming at least Android 3.0, or before 1.6.  Between 1.6 and 2.3 they actually executed on parallel threads by default.  Then Google realized too many people can't write multithreaded code.