# Android app crashed on second AsyncTask call?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm running the app on lollipop so according to some pros, the default asynctask run is serialized. The app is going to first authenticate an Instagram user then ask Instagram for some content of the user. First step that is first AsyncTask call works fine, but the second call makes the app carsh!
LogCat massage is: java.lang.RunTimeException, An error occured while executing doInBackground.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private WebView webView;
private String code;
private String myToken;
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String myUrl  = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI&response_type=code";
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView wView, String url) {
               if (url.indexOf(REDIRECT_URI) > -1) {
                   code = url.substring(28, url.length());
                   runAsync();                    
                   return true;
               } else
                   return false; 
               }
       });
    webView.loadUrl(myUrl);
}

private void runAsync(){
    //first call which works fine and gains access_token
    new MyHttpsPost().execute(
           new String ("https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token"),
           new String ("client_id="),
           new String ("&client_secret="),
           new String ("&grant_type="),
           new String ("&redirect_uri="),
           new String ("&code="),
           new String (CLIENT_ID),
           new String (CLIENT_SECRET),
           new String ("authorization_code"),
           new String (REDIRECT_URI),
           new String (code),

           new String (""),
           new String (""),
           new String (""),
           new String (""),
           new String (""),
           new String ("access_token"),
           new String (""),
           new String (""),
           new String (""),
           new String ("")
           );
    //second call which makes the app crash, "error while executing doInBackground"
    new MyHttpsPost().execute(
           new String ("https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/popular?access_token=" + myToken),
           new String (""),
           new String (""),
           new String (""),
           new String (""),
           new String (""),
           new String (""),
           new String (""),
           new String (""),
           new String (""),
           new String (""),

           new String (""),
           new String (""),
           new String (""),
           new String (""),
           new String (""),
           new String ("data"),
           new String (""),
           new String (""),
           new String (""),
           new String ("")
           );
}

class MyHttpsPost extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

   URL murl;
   HttpsURLConnection conn;
   String response= "";

   try{
   murl=new URL(params[0]);

   String param=
   params[1]     +URLEncoder.encode(params[6],"UTF-8")+
   params[2]+URLEncoder.encode(params[7],"UTF-8")+
   params[3]   +URLEncoder.encode(params[8],"UTF-8")+
   params[4] +URLEncoder.encode(params[9],"UTF-8")+
   params[5]         +URLEncoder.encode(params[10],"UTF-8");

   conn=(HttpsURLConnection)murl.openConnection();
   conn.setDoOutput(true);
   conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
   conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(param.getBytes().length);
   conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

   PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(conn.getOutputStream()); 
   out.print(param);
   out.close(); 

   Scanner inStream = new Scanner(conn.getInputStream());
   while(inStream.hasNextLine())
   response+=(inStream.nextLine());

   }
   catch(MalformedURLException ex){
   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ex.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
   }
   catch(IOException ex){
   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ex.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
   }

  try {
        JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) new      JSONTokener(response).nextValue();
        params[11] = jsonObj.getString(params[16]);
        params[12] = jsonObj.getString(params[17]);         
        params[13] = jsonObj.getString(params[18]);
        params[14] = jsonObj.getString(params[19]);
        params[15] = jsonObj.getString(params[20]);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    myToken = params[11];
    return params[11];      
}    
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), result , Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
    TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    txt.setText(result);    
}    
}
```

Here is LogCat:

```
      10-29 15:10:02.989: D/ResourcesManager(20355): creating new AssetManager and set to /data/app/com.example.webview-2/base.apk
      10-29 15:10:03.044: V/BitmapFactory(20355): DecodeImagePath(decodeResourceStream3) : res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/ic_ab_back_holo_dark_am.png
      10-29 15:10:03.064: V/BitmapFactory(20355): DecodeImagePath(decodeResourceStream3) : res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/sym_def_app_icon.png
      10-29 15:10:03.134: I/WebViewFactory(20355): Loading com.google.android.webview version 42.0.2311.129 (code 2311129)
      10-29 15:10:03.134: D/ResourcesManager(20355): creating new AssetManager and set to /system/app/WebViewGoogle/WebViewGoogle.apk
      10-29 15:10:03.164: I/LibraryLoader(20355): Time to load native libraries: 2 ms (timestamps 4641-4643)
      10-29 15:10:03.164: I/LibraryLoader(20355): Expected native library version number "",actual native library version number ""
      10-29 15:10:03.214: V/WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider(20355): Binding Chromium to main looper Looper (main, tid 1) {18bd9fce}
      10-29 15:10:03.214: I/LibraryLoader(20355): Expected native library version number "",actual native library version number ""
      10-29 15:10:03.214: I/chromium(20355): [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(112)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
      10-29 15:10:03.239: I/BrowserStartupController(20355): Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=true
      10-29 15:10:03.244: W/art(20355): Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
      10-29 15:10:03.244: E/SysUtils(20355): ApplicationContext is null in ApplicationStatus
      10-29 15:10:03.269: W/AudioManagerAndroid(20355): Requires BLUETOOTH permission
      10-29 15:10:03.269: W/chromium(20355): [WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(286)] locale_file_path.empty()
      10-29 15:10:03.269: I/chromium(20355): [INFO:aw_browser_main_parts.cc(63)] Load from apk succesful, fd=42 off=50364 len=3345
      10-29 15:10:03.269: I/chromium(20355): [INFO:aw_browser_main_parts.cc(76)] Loading webviewchromium.pak from, fd:43 off:7953004 len:1161174
      10-29 15:10:03.274: I/(20355): PLATFORM VERSION : JB-MR-2
      10-29 15:10:03.414: W/chromium(20355): [WARNING:data_reduction_proxy_config.cc(150)] SPDY proxy OFF at startup
      10-29 15:10:03.439: W/art(20355): Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
      10-29 15:10:03.459: W/AwContents(20355): onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
      10-29 15:10:03.474: V/BitmapFactory(20355): DecodeImagePath(decodeResourceStream3) : res/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_launcher.png
      10-29 15:10:03.514: D/Activity(20355): performCreate Call secproduct feature valuefalse
      10-29 15:10:03.514: D/Activity(20355): performCreate Call debug elastic valuetrue
      10-29 15:10:03.534: D/OpenGLRenderer(20355): Render dirty regions requested: true
      10-29 15:10:03.539: D/Atlas(20355): Validating map...
      10-29 15:10:03.594: I/OpenGLRenderer(20355): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
      10-29 15:10:03.604: I/OpenGLRenderer(20355): HWUI protection enabled for context ,  &this =0x9f5c0060 ,&mEglDisplay = 1 , &mEglConfig = -1282169932 
      10-29 15:10:03.614: D/OpenGLRenderer(20355): Enabling debug mode 0
      10-29 15:10:03.769: I/Timeline(20355): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@2d6ba73d time:232065247
      10-29 15:10:08.609: W/BindingManager(20355): Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 20355
      10-29 15:10:08.684: I/System.out(20355): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
      10-29 15:10:08.684: I/System.out(20355): (HTTPLog)-Static: isShipBuild true
      10-29 15:10:08.684: I/System.out(20355): (HTTPLog)-Thread-50224-192410000: SmartBonding Enabling is false, SHIP_BUILD is true, log to file is false, DBG is false
      10-29 15:10:08.684: I/System.out(20355): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
      10-29 15:10:08.964: I/System.out(20355): KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false
      10-29 15:10:10.109: W/System.err(20355): org.json.JSONException: No value for 
      10-29 15:10:10.114: W/System.err(20355):  at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389)
      10-29 15:10:10.114: W/System.err(20355):  at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:550)
      10-29 15:10:10.119: W/System.err(20355):  at com.example.webview.MainActivity$MyHttpsPost.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:172)
      10-29 15:10:10.119: W/System.err(20355):  at com.example.webview.MainActivity$MyHttpsPost.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
      10-29 15:10:10.119: W/System.err(20355):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
      10-29 15:10:10.119: W/System.err(20355):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
      10-29 15:10:10.119: W/System.err(20355):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
      10-29 15:10:10.119: W/System.err(20355):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
      10-29 15:10:10.119: W/System.err(20355):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
      10-29 15:10:10.119: W/System.err(20355):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
      10-29 15:10:10.129: I/System.out(20355): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
      10-29 15:10:10.419: E/AndroidRuntime(20355): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
      10-29 15:10:10.419: E/AndroidRuntime(20355): Process: com.example.webview, PID: 20355
      10-29 15:10:10.419: E/AndroidRuntime(20355): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
      10-29 15:10:10.419: E/AndroidRuntime(20355):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
      10-29 15:10:10.419: E/AndroidRuntime(20355):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
      10-29 15:10:10.419: E/AndroidRuntime(20355):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
      10-29 15:10:10.419: E/AndroidRuntime(20355):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
      10-29 15:10:10.419: E/AndroidRuntime(20355):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
      10-29 15:10:10.419: E/AndroidRuntime(20355):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
      10-29 15:10:10.419: E/AndroidRuntime(20355):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
      10-29 15:10:10.419: E/AndroidRuntime(20355):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
      10-29 15:10:10.419: E/AndroidRuntime(20355): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
      10-29 15:10:10.419: E/AndroidRuntime(20355):  at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
      10-29 15:10:10.419: E/AndroidRuntime(20355):  at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
      10-29 15:10:10.419: E/AndroidRuntime(20355):  at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:487)
      10-29 15:10:10.419: E/AndroidRuntime(20355):  at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:121)
      10-29 15:10:10.419: E/AndroidRuntime(20355):  at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:290)
      10-29 15:10:10.419: E/AndroidRuntime(20355):  at com.example.webview.MainActivity$MyHttpsPost.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:163)
      10-29 15:10:10.419: E/AndroidRuntime(20355):  at com.example.webview.MainActivity$MyHttpsPost.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
      10-29 15:10:10.419: E/AndroidRuntime(20355):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
      10-29 15:10:10.419: E/AndroidRuntime(20355):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
      10-29 15:10:10.419: E/AndroidRuntime(20355):  ... 4 more
```

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace, why does your app crash? What exception?

Comment: If you could check also on which line error occurs. The diffrerence between two calls is only in parameters, so maybe encoding empty string is wrong.

Comment: It's not of encoding. I put both params and jasonObject in if (is not null) statement and error kept continuing.

Comment: Edit your question, post the logcat, and perhaps the androidmanifest related parts.

Comment: I'm trying to post the logcat but it's too messy. i don't know how to bring it in order?!

Comment: @xvxph Post it and i'll edit it your question.

Comment: Thank you Marko. I managed to find a way to post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your exception indicates that you're trying to update the UI from doInBackground(), which you shouldn't.

Looking at your code the only place you're doing so is in:

```
catch(MalformedURLException ex){
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ex.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
 }
catch(IOException ex){
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ex.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
 }
```

So your first problem is that you get an exception which you catch, but then you try to Toast it, and get an unhandled exception.

So remove this Toast, but offcourse check why you're getting an exception in the first place.

Comment: Thanks. after removing toasts, the crash stopped. but still i can't receive correct response for the second call because after successfully setting the first call response to both textView and toast at onPostExecute, the second call just sets a blank toast and textView which is the root cause for exception. I'm checking it.

Comment: You should try this call first without the complexity of all these params, see that it works, and only then try this code.

Comment: I exactly did that. I even used another asynctask calss for second call without complexity of parameters but the result was the same.

Comment: What's the response you're getting?

Comment: after second call, both toast and textView show empty messages. by the way, even with a fake url in the second call, result still is the same! so i guess second call sets no connection in fact!

Comment: debug your request and response, see explicitly what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't in the Asynctask, it's in your JSON or the way you serialize it. This line of your logcat shows that:

10-29 15:10:10.109: W/System.err(20355): org.json.JSONException: No value for 
  10-29 15:10:10.114: W/System.err(20355):  at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389)

Check what response you get from the webservice, and check if the way you deserialize the JSON is correct.

My best guess is the fact that your `params` array is mostly empty is causing the errors. You're basically doing `json.getString("")`, is your JSON filled with empty keys?

**Edit**

Udi Idan is right, the direct cause of this crash is calling a Toast.show() on the UI thread (which you cannot do), but also beware that the app is catching a JSONException before that, so you'll end up having troubles with that too.

In order to execute something on the UI thread while you're working in an AsyncTask is to execute it on the `onPostExecute(result)` method, this is executed on the main (ui) thread.

Another way would be creating a runnable and executing it on the UI thread like so:

```
Runnable toastRunnable = new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "My Toast message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
    }
};

context.runOnUiThread(toastRunnable);
```