# Android: How multiple separate async tasks work?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, retrofit

In my Android program, I have to do 4 or 5 network calls. Each are independent, and each can run on their own.

```
public void backGroundTasks() {

    new AsyncTasks<Void, Void, Void>() {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {

                List<User> users = RetrofitAdapter.getClient().getUsersSync();

                saveToDB(users);

            } catch (RetrofitError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }.execute();

    new AsyncTasks<Void, Void, Void>() {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {

                List<Media> contents = RetrofitAdapter.getClient().getContentsSync();

                saveToDB(contents);

            } catch (RetrofitError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }.execute();

    new AsyncTasks<Void, Void, Void>() {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {

                Profile profile = RetrofitAdapter.getClient().getProfile();

                saveToDB(profile);

            } catch (RetrofitError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }.execute();

    new AsyncTasks<Void, Void, Void>() {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {

                List<Message> messages = RetrofitAdapter.getClient().getMessages();

                saveToDB(messages);

            } catch (RetrofitError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }.execute();

}
```

My questions are,

How this `AsyncTask` work ? 
Will be executed in **parallel** ? or Will be invoked but the ***network requests*** will be queued ?

In some SO answers they have mentioned to do execute `AsyncTasks` with `executeOnExecutor()`. Will it help for this scenario ?

Note: 
I use Retrofit library for making REST calls easier. Does it have anything with this problem ?

Comment: What exactly *is* the problem?

Answer (score 1):

> How this AsyncTask work ? Will be executed in parallel ?

Since honeycomb they will be executed serially, but if you will use executeOnExecutor then they will be executed in parallel.

> or Will be invoked but the network requests will be queued ?

they will be queued, no network operation will start untill AsyncTask will get its turn.

Internally AsyncTasks use [Executors](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html). Your tasks only execute network operation, so you might switch to Executors. If you want to do your network operations serially, then you might also consider using [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html).

Answer (score 1):

This is answer by **Arhimed**. He explained it well.

AsyncTask uses a thread pool pattern for running the stuff from doInBackground(). The issue is initially (in early Android OS versions) the pool size was just 1, meaning no parallel computations for a bunch of AsyncTasks. But later they fixed that and now the size is 5, so at most 5 AsyncTasks can run simultaneously. Unfortunately I don't remember in what version exactly they changed that.

For more check his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4072832/5275639)

Answer (score 1):

`Executors` with `AsyncTasks` works like charm. It executes the network requests concurrently.

From the docs,

> Since Honeycomb, invoking AsyncTask's `executeOnExecutor()` instead of `execute()` will execute tasks in parallel.
>
> [AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR)
>
> An Executor that can be used to execute tasks in parallel.