# How to run two concurrent services in android

Tags: android, syncservices

i have created two services for timer but when i run both one wait until first is finished,so my question is how to run them concurrently.

Thanks,Dk

Comment: Check this link : [LInk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068984/running-multiple-asynctasks-at-the-same-time-not-possible)

Comment: i have to run service,thanx for comment

Comment: there should not be any such problem, a service runs whenever it finds `startService`, are you sure it's waiting for the first one to finish?

Comment: not sure,i have to check out again