# how to run single service paralley android?

Tags: android, service

I came to know that if a service running already, next time it won't to go to oncreate, How to run two services at a time, paralley?, I want all the steps to be excecuted for both services I run.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running multiple AsyncTasks at the same time -- not possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068984/running-multiple-asynctasks-at-the-same-time-not-possible)

Comment: I don't really understand what you would like to do? Be more specific please

Comment: I have a service which retrieves profile data from server based on user name, Consider I want to load two persons profile data when app starts, here when I am calling one after another, only one is excecuting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Service has its own life cycle. This means if you want to start the same service twice you have to start it, destroy it then recreate it (BAD implementation!!)

You have several API in the android framework allowing you to get data asynchrounously (Asynctask, Intentservice....). I think you should have a look on these ones(one of them should be more appropriate in your case)

Notice service must be your last choice because you have to manage its lifecycle. For example when your app is destroy you must manually stop your service. Otherwise it will always be running