# Running 3 methods at the same using AsyncTask

Tags: android, multithreading

I have a problem using `AsyncTask`.

I have 3 methods that I want to run at the same time.

How can I do that using `AsyncTask` in Android OpenCV?

public class DoTask extends AsyncTask{

```
@Override
protected  Void doInBackground( Void... params) {

    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {


         }
    });
    return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068984/running-multiple-asynctasks-at-the-same-time-not-possible

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class DoTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        yourActvity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                  DrawLetter1();
                  DrawLetter2();
                  DrawLetter3();
            }
        });}
```

Comment: DrawLetter methods in another class. public class CircleDetection extends Activity and when I write other class in AsyncTask DrawLetter methods does not run. I couldnt extend or implement another class in asynctask class

Comment: Create Circle Class Object As Globle and Access those Methods by Object.DrawLetter1();  Ex. CircleClass circleclass=new CircleClass();  in AsynkTask circleclass.DrawLetter1();

Comment: How to create class object as global?

Comment: Thank you! But how did you define  runOnUiThread method? This part give an error

Comment: if (id == R.id.draw_letter) {

}

How can I call asynctask class in here?