# Android create service in new thread

Tags: android, multithreading, service

Hi i have listview with custom adapter on bindviewholder i have:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final AdapterRecyclerViewEventiComposti.ViewHolder holder, final int position)
{
    String tmp=listaEventiComposti.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(tmp);
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            context.startService(new Intent(context, GestioneEvento.class));

        }
    });
}
```

When i click on item on listview i execute GestioneEvento that extends Service into method onStartCommand i have:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, final int startId) {
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            //execute my operations

        }
    }; 
   Thread t = new Thread(r);
    t.start();
    return Service.START_STICKY;
  }
```

I want to that when i click on item of listview i create a new thread and every life cycle of thread is separated. For example:
ListView
Item1
Item2
Item3

I click on Item1 and start new thread, immediately after i click Item2 and start new thread, then i click again Item1 and i stop only thread of Item1 while Item2 continues to work in the background. 
So as I did above is correct?
Now if i want only stop thread of Item1 how should I do?

Comment: I don't think that this is better implementation to create so many threads on item click of list. To do some common task use asyncTask instead of service.

Comment: I want that it work in background therefore i use service

Comment: AsyncTask also have doInBackground which works in background and also you can also create/cancel different instance of it.   Try it.

Comment: Can you poste guide where explain all?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4072832/3728591