# What happens if same AsyncTask is called multiple times with different parameter in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I have a question about AsyncTask. If I am calling the same AsyncTask using different string values like this

```
 next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
              new MyAsyncTask().execute("Android");
new MyAsyncTask().execute("Java");
new MyAsyncTask().execute("Hadoop");
new MyAsyncTask().execute("Python");
new MyAsyncTask().execute("Dot Net");
new MyAsyncTask().execute("Hibernate");
        }
    });
```

I am calling the same AsyncTask with different values using a single button click. Now my question is, what will happen in the above code? Will all the AsyncTasks execute in parallel or sequentially? If they execute in parallel how? If they execute sequentially how? I want a clear explanation. If any one knows please tell me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would highly recommend you to read Asynctask usage and how it works.Asynctask is designed to work on thread operations , It depends on your ThreadPoolSize as to the number of asyntasks which could run parallely.

Comment: if you have to pass multiple parameter then use variable instead of this `java` string and assign string to variable base on your condition

Answer (score 1):

`AsyncTask` uses a thread pool pattern for running the stuff from `doInBackground()`. The issue is initially (in early Android OS versions) the pool size was just 1, meaning no parallel computations for a bunch of `AsyncTasks`. But later they fixed that and now the size is 5, so at most 5 `AsyncTasks` can run simultaneously.

Find More details in below link:

[Running multiple AsyncTasks at the same time — not possible?

[Multiple AsyncTask In Android](http://blogs.innovationm.com/multiple-asynctask-in-android/)
][2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068984/running-multiple-asynctasks-at-the-same-time-not-possible)

**Thread Pool Pattern**

`AsyncTask` uses a thread pool pattern for running the stuff from `doInBackground()`

The Thread pool Pattern is where number of Threads are created to perform a number of Tasks. It is basically a container where multiple threads come in a queue for different task.

**Multiple `AsyncTasks` In Android**

In earlier version of Android `(Donut and below)`, multiple `AsyncTasks` execution were not allowed. The pool size was just 1. But after `Donut (1.6)` it has been relaxed and now the size is 5, so at most 5 `AsyncTasks` can run simultaneously.

**Limitation Of `AsyncTask`**

There is a limit of how many tasks can be run simultaneously. Since `AsyncTask` uses a thread pool executor with max number of worker threads (128) and the delayed tasks queue has fixed size 10. If you try to execute more than 138 `AsyncTasks` the app will crash with `java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException`.

**Delayed Queue Size**

`AsyncTasks` use a fixed size queue internally for storing delayed tasks. Queue size is 10 by default. If you start 15 `AsyncTasks` in a row, then first 5 will enter their `doInBackground()`, but the rest will wait in a queue for a free worker thread. As soon as any of the first 5 `AsyncTasks` finishes, and thus releases a worker thread, a task from the queue will start execution. So in this case at most 5 tasks will run simultaneously. However if you start 16 your custom tasks in a row, then first 5 will enter their `doInBackground()`, the rest 10 will get into the queue, but for the 16th, a new worker thread will be created so it’ll start execution immediately. So in this case at most 6 tasks will run simultaneously.

Comment: ok the size is 5 means, if i am run more than 5 asynctask then what will happen?? if i am run 10 means, first 5 execute simultaneously and next 5 will execute simultaneously .. am i right??

Comment: read second link it has complete information regarding ,`Multiple AsyncTasks In Android`, `Limitation Of AsyncTask` , `Delayed Queue Size`