# android loop inside asynctask or asynctask inside loop

Tags: android, loops, android-asynctask

I have list of items to be syncronized with cloud. Let's say it has 10 items, so I have to make 10 HTTP requests to server. The question is: which approach should I use and why?

1. foreach loop inside one async task
2. 10 async tasks inside foreach loop?

Comment: Will you handle (and present) the data from each HTTP separately?

Answer (score 2):

Better would be to have one `AsyncTask` and loop in in. And here is why:
All `AsyncTasks` will by default on one background thread (with API 11+, eg Honeycomb), so your 10 tasks will still execute sequentially, but meanwhile will take much more memory. So it's really better to run only one `AsyncTask` and if you need - `publishProgress` on execution process.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4072832/4850642) is SO answer about having multiple `AsyncTask`s.

Another approach is passing `Executor` to your `AsyncTask`, so it can break the limit of simultaneously runned `AsyncTask`s. But still it can be really memory consuming.

Aslo you might want to read [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) Android Developers guide.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and links. Additional reason to use one async task just came to my mind: In case of problems with connection I have to handle as many connection errors as tasks I've lounched.