# Do images with AsyncTask download parallel or sequentially?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I made the AsyncTask to load images for my RecyclerView. It has method downloadImage() which I call every time at ViewHolder. So for each image it should create new AsyncTask? I can't figure out if it download parallel or sequentially. (I can't use libraries, all must be custom)

```
private static class DownloadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

    private ImageView mBitmapImage;

    DownloadImage(ImageView imageView) {
        mBitmapImage = imageView;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String url = strings[0];
        Bitmap bitmapImage = null;
        InputStream in = null;

        try {
            in = new URL(url).openStream();
            bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return bitmapImage;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        if (result != null) {
            mBitmapImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        } else {
            mBitmapImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.loading_movie);
        }
    }
}

public static void downloadImage(String imageLocation, ImageView imageView) {
    new DownloadImage(imageView).execute(MOVIE_POSTER_URL_REQUEST + imageLocation);
}
```

In adapter I call it like this:

```
void bindMovie(Movie movie) {
        mMovie = movie;
        mMovieTitle.setText(movie.getTitle());
        mDescription.setText(movie.getOverview());
        downloadImage(movie.getPosterPath(), mPoster);
    }
```

Comment: Just one question, why can't you use any library?

Comment: @Kunu
Teamlead said to write all by myself, I'm a trainee developer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on the version of Android system.

But if you want to be sure to execute tasks in parallel, use this (from support v.4 library): `AsyncTaskCompat.executeParallel(task, params);`

In-depth explanation (see the accepted answer): [Running multiple AsyncTasks at the same time -- not possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068984/running-multiple-asynctasks-at-the-same-time-not-possible/4072832#4072832)

**UPDATE:**

As you fairly stated, `AsyncTaskCompat.executeParallel(task, params);` is now deprecated in API 26, though i couldn't find an explanation why.

So, as the docs are saying, instead you should use [`asyncTask.executeOnExecutor(task, params);`](http://asyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,%20params);)

To achieve parallel execution:

`asyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, params);`

> This method is typically used with THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR to allow multiple tasks to run in parallel on a pool of threads managed by AsyncTask, however you can also use your own Executor for custom behavior.

Answer (score 1):

> Do images with AsyncTask download parallel or sequentially?

For Honeycomb and up, default is a serial executor, which executes tasks one by one. But you can pass a `ThreadPoolExecutor` for execution: