# simultaneous REST requests and async tasks

Tags: android, multithreading, rest, android-asynctask, httpurlconnection

In my Android application, I use to call more AsyncTasks in order to execute REST requests to a server (GET/POST to retrieve images, and other informations as real-time feed).
Imagine a scenario like this:
I have a main activity with a ListView and an associated Adapter showing a lot of views having images. These images are loaded dinamically from cache or if missing from web through a REST request to a server.
The request operate as follow:
-the app instantiate a new AsyncTask having in doInBackground a POST request (for example) with HttpUrlConnection class. When the response is ready and retrieved I execute a callback to the java class that needs the info.

The problem is present when a request is waiting for result and the other requests are freezed for completion of the first. Imagine that the server take time to elaborate a request and a set of images needs to be loaded. The first take a while and block the loading of other images taking GUI incomplete.

How can I manage simultaneous tasks with REST requests? Is AsyncTask the right way to operate or should I use something else?

Thank you

Comment: starting form some Android version (2.3 probably) all AsyncTasks are executed on a single background thread (one by one therefore). You should execute them on custom executor

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running multiple AsyncTasks at the same time -- not possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068984/running-multiple-asynctasks-at-the-same-time-not-possible)

Comment: but anyway I'd recommend you to use one of the popular image loading libraries (Picasso, Glide) to load images instead of creating your own way.