# execute several asynchronous methods at the same time

Tags: java, android

I have 3 asynchronous methods:

1 - Update Data
2 - Validate Data
3 - Enter

Currently I have the class as follows:

```
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
        setContentView (R.layout.activity_sync);
....

new Update (). execute ();
new Validate () .execute ();
new Enter (). execute ();
}
```

It is assumed that they all have to execute at the same time however they expect to have an answer from the previous one.

How can I make them all run at the same time without waiting for the previous one to finish?

Comment: Best way I believe would be [ExecutorService.invokeAll();](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll(java.util.Collection))

Comment: I use asynchronous classes

Example:

private class Update extends AsyncTask <Void, Boolean, Boolean> {
...
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **.executeOnExecutor()*** instead of .execute() to run multiple `AsynchTask` at the same time like this:

*** Works from API level 11 or onward**

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
     new Update().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
     new Validate().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
     new Enter().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
}
 else {
     new Update().execute();
     new Validate().execute();
     new Enter().execute();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked,
It can be done with all asynchronous methods or has some limit?

Comment: Yes it has some limitations, you can find here https://stackoverflow.com/a/4072832/1427776

Answer (score 0):

You should run each method in a separate thread.
Make Update, Validate, Enter implement Runnable.
In the run() method call execute() or rename execute() to run().
Then

```
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(poolSize);;
pool.execute(new Update());
pool.execute(new Validate());
pool.execute(new Enter());
```

Comment: How can I get the ExecutorService.execute?

Comment: I edited the question. The answer implied that ExecutorService was a static component, while in fact, it isn't.